# Using public ip to access webserver pages when computer is connected via Android hot-spot wifi

Tags: android, apache, ip, mamp, hotspot

I know it might be unusual, but I would like to be able to access my personal website, hosted on my computer, even when the WiFi connection of the computer is my android phone's hot-spot. 
I can use the local ip without problem to access the website both on my phone and on the computer itself. 
But how can I access the website with a public ip? Both phone and computer share the same public ip.

When I am connected to my home WiFi, I know how to setup my router to make the website available publicly. What would be the equivalent for Android's hot-spot?

Comment: From where do you want to do the access? Unclear what you want exactly.

Comment: From anywhere other than my phone and computer. Let me rephrase: my phone has LTE network through my phone contract. I generate a hotspot from it. Using the wifi, I connect my computer to this hotspot. On my computer is an apache server. And I want to access the website with the real public ip address, from anywhere, not just phone and computer.

Answer (score 2):

Your phone will have an ip. You are not mentioning a mobile connection but i suppose the phone has mobile connection when it acts as a hotspot.

It makes little sense to call that a public ip as the mobile provider will block incoming connections. So you cannot run servers on your phone or on your pc connected with the hotspot.

Acting as hotspot or not, a server running on your phone can never be reached from the outside world using a mobile connection.

Comment: server is running on computer, not phone. But the computer is connected to the phone's hotspot.

Comment: I knew that all. Why did you repeat? Without further comment?

Comment: because you said "a server running on your phone". Well, technically, the server is not running on my phone...

Comment: If the request does not even reach your phone then how could it be forwarded to your pc? Thats the problem. The provider blocks incoming connections. Thats the cause of the impossibility.

Comment: Oh I see. So I need a server on my phone first, and then a way to forward the request to computer, is that what you're saying? is it feasible?

Comment: No. Read my post again please. As i clearly stated that even a server on your phone is unreachable. Incoming connections are blocked.

Comment: i see. it's very unfortunate

Comment: Just for your own sake off mind: start a server on your phone (many ftp servers in app store) and see that you can reach it using wifi but not over the mobile connection.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I just realized that the best compromise would be to ask the third device to connect to the hotspot instead of staying on its own internet connection. Then I can access my 192.168.x.x . Of course, this option is still not valid when using ownCloud, that blocks all 'numerical' IPs.

Comment: would there be a way to access a page as http://localhost/ instead of http://192.168.x.x on another machine (connected to the same hotspot) than the server one?

Comment: Every device is it's own localhost with ip 127.0.0.1. So you are talking in the wrong way over a localhost. Your phone is localhost. Your computer is localhost. My tablet is localhost. Every device is...Localhost or 127.0.01 can only be used by a client trying to connect with a server running on the same machine as it does.

Comment: Ok, I shouldn't have used the word localhost. For me, 'localhost' is an alias for 127.0.0.1. how can I configure my server (on computer) so that if I type "http://myoch" on my phone with ip 192.168.43.1, it redirects to http://192.168.43.63, the actual ip of my computer?

Comment: I guess now what I want to do is something like no-ip.com, but for local networks...

Comment: You do not have to specially configure your sever for that as it accepts already incoming connections i suppose. Is 192.168.43.63 a static ip? If it is obtained by DHCP then it would change at reboot and how would a client know it?